# Using Nth-Child With Span Elements - All Span Elements Are Odd For Some Reason

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the `nth-child` pseudo selector to target even an odd spans in a containing div. My HTML markup looks like this.

```
<div class="load-data">
<span>Company: Heavy Haul LLC.</span><br> 
<span>Name: John Smith</span><br> 
<span>Phone: (123)-456-7890</span><br> 
<span>Position: Chase</span><br> 
<span>From: Knoxville, TN</span><br> 
<span>To: Nashville, TN</span><br> 
<span>Date: 03/02/2016</span><br> 
<span>Rate: $250 Day Rate</span><br> 
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
.load-data {
 border: 1px solid #454545;
 background-color: #121212;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px 10px;
 text-align: left;
}
.load-data > span {
 padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.load-data span:nth-child(even) {
 color: #ff6400;
}
.load-data span:nth-child(odd) {
 color: #ff9900;
}
```

But for some reason every `span` element has the color of `ff9900`. Why would they all be odd numbers?

For debugging I did try using `nth-child(5)` just to see what happens and the third line was selected for some reason instead of the fifth one.

I'm not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: Use nth-of-type instead, It's counting <br> as a child or use div instead of span and get rid of the br

Comment: I see. I can probably just remove the <br> tags.

Comment: Then you'll need to make the spans block. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Choices

1. Use `nth-of-type` instead, It's counting `<br>` as a child.
2. Use `nth-child` and div instead of span and get rid of the `<br>`.

If you simply remove the `<br>` and use `nth-child` you'll get a mess since `<span>` are `inline`, see second example.

At that point you either change the`<span>` by assigning this to your CSS:

```
span { display: block; }
```

Or change `<span>` into `<div>`

**Snippet**

```css
.load-data span:nth-of-type(even) { background: blue; }
.load-data span:nth-of-type(odd) { background: red; }
.x span:nth-child(even) { background: blue; }
.x span:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="load-data">
<span>Company: Heavy Haul LLC.</span><br> 
<span>Name: John Smith</span><br> 
<span>Phone: (123)-456-7890</span><br> 
<span>Position: Chase</span><br> 
<span>From: Knoxville, TN</span><br> 
<span>To: Nashville, TN</span><br> 
<span>Date: 03/02/2016</span><br> 
<span>Rate: $250 Day Rate</span><br> 
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="x">
<span>Company: Heavy Haul LLC.</span>
<span>Name: John Smith</span>
<span>Phone: (123)-456-7890</span>
<span>Position: Chase</span>
<span>From: Knoxville, TN</span> 
<span>To: Nashville, TN</span> 
<span>Date: 03/02/2016</span>
<span>Rate: $250 Day Rate</span> 
</div>
```